# Running a Unix shell script from simple HTML button input

Tags: http

I've been Googling all afternoon with no luck, so I've come to you for help!

I have an embedded system that is hosting the simplest of web pages:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <input type="button" value="Run" action="">
</body>
</html>
```

There is a little more to the page (just some system variables on display), but this is basically all it is.  I generate this page from a simple C application that simply creates and updates a small run.html file in the web directory of my embedded system.

What I am TRYING to do, is when a user browses to the page and presses the button, a simple shell script or c app will create a tiny go.txt file with perhaps two characters 'GO' in the file.  Just some kind of file to allow another application to eventually know that the button has been pressed.

I theorize that there is some syntax like `action="/root/fs/go.sh"` that might allow me this kind of access, but my experimentation has yielded no success.  I should note that PHP is not enabled on the machine we are using.

My question for the group:  is it this simple?  Or am I missing some obvious web technology issue and going down a completely wrong path?  Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the desired behaviour, you will have to do some works on the Web server.  You will need to have some code on the server that will run the script you want upon receiving the form.  The code on the server could be pretty much anything: a PHP script, a CGI application you coded in C, a custom Apache module, etc.

The bottom of this is, you will have to code something on the server side to do support that behavior.  There is nothing in the HTML standard that let client request any script to be run on the server.

Comment: +1 Depending on the specs of your embedded platform, you might find something like Mongoose useful http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/

Comment: Laurent, thank you for your feedback.  I am not the most web-savvy, but now I know which direction to look.  A CGI app in C seems very doable.  Also, MONGOOSE, what a wonderful little server!  Thank you both for your suggestions.